# ScrollView inside Framelayout with BottomNavigationView not scrolling in android

Tags: android, scrollview, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to create an application with `BottomNavigationView`. For that i use Bottom navigation activity template in android studio. In a fragment i use `ScrollView` as top view. But it doesn't scroll. but if i use fixed height in dp to `ScrollView` it works properly else it does not scroll. here is my code for layouts
homeactivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.avantika.queueadmin.activities.HomeActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
        />


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

adduserfragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.avantika.queueadmin.fragments.AddUserFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextAddUserFullName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Full Name"
                android:inputType="text" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextAddUserDisplayName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Display Name"
                android:inputType="text" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextAddUserMobile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Mobile No"
                android:inputType="number|phone" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextAddUserEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="text|textEmailAddress" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextAddUserAddress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Address"
                android:inputType="text|textMultiLine" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextAddUserUserName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="User Name"
                android:inputType="text" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerAddUserGender"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAddUserSave"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Add Employee" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: try  android:layout_height="wrap_content" for your linear layout.

Comment: i create a new screen and its working but not in old anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the height of `FramenLayout`(`fragment_frame`) to `wrap_content`. And same for the `ScrollView`.